# Can not get input value from controller, Opencart:3

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3, opencart2.3

i am converting a .tpl module to opencart3(.twig), which is done. I have placed all other (model and controller) files in their location too. But i am getting a strange error, which is i can not get values of input and image fields. input is placed obviousely in .twig file and i am Using Journal 3 Theme.

Here is my twig file: theme/journal3/template/journal3/checkout/checkout.twig

```
<div class="tab-pane tab-content {% if (not previousreceiptlist) %}active{% endif %}" id="newreceipts">
    <div class="images form-group"></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
     <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Prescription ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reciept_name" value="1234" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="test_name" placeholder="Test Name" value="090" />

    </div>
    <div class="form-group required" style="text-align:left;">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Prescription</label>
        <button style="background-color: #F44336;" type="button" id="newreceiptsbutton" data-loading-text="Loading.." class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Prescription</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

But i can not access it from controller by  --controller/journal3/checkout.php

```
$this->request->post['reciept_name'])
```

is there anything i am missing? Any suggestion what can i try...

Thankyou in advance

Comment: The only comment I can make is that "reciept" is misspelled in this question, so maybe it's spelled correctly on the form as "receipt"? Maybe add `$this->log->write(json_encode($this->request->post));` to the controller method and inspect the logs

Comment: @Daniel - I just noticed that, in journl theme: to get other fields data like coupon--etc they don't use name, instead they used v-model="coupon" inside a input field.

Comment: so, when i tried same like: <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="reciept_name" value="1234" /> ---- then checkout part got blank. How can i deal this, any suggestion?

Comment: Also with this: $this->log->write(json_encode($this->request->post)); I cannot see reciept_name in log.

Comment: That's strange, what action is triggered in javascript on the Button click?